# Angular model update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reference

I am trying out Angular for the first time and using the following library https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps.

My issue is when I push new markers to my array $scope.marker, the map directive does not update to show the added markers on the map (existing markers show correctly).

I am fairly sure the issue is because the markers array still points to the same reference when pushing new elements resulting in the relevant listeners not being fired. I managed to prove this by firing a new request to server to re-set $scope.marker which worked but this does not seem very efficient.

Is there any appropriate solution to have the directive update based on object equality, failing that I have seen some documentation for angular.copy that might do what I need

Comment: Could we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a single line of code, it's hard to give a 100% accurate answer, but sounds like you need to force a scope digest cycle after pushing new markers.

So, either use `$scope.$apply()` or wrap the push code in a `$timeout` callback, and you should be forcing the map update with the new markers.

Comment: I tried using $scope.$apply() without any luck, I thought that it may be because the array is still the same instance? edit - actually using $scope.$apply() results in the following error 'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress'

Comment: Being the same instance is actually what I tried to fix by forcing a digest cycle. Try wrapping it in a $timeout callback.

Comment: Could you show me an example of what that would look like?

Comment: Using angular.copy definitely fixed the issue so it does appear that for what ever reason the maps directive is not being told about the new element in the array due to the array being the same instance :(, I would give up and stick with copying the array but that messes up the animations I have with ngAnimate :(

Comment: Can't give you an example because I have no idea what your code looks like. `$timeout(function(){array.push(el);});`